# How to provide a 'real time' update in Table View Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I've created a Tableview that shows players (bees) and their attributes. You can level up the players too, however this upgrade isn't shown in real time. I have to scroll all the way down on the TableView, then scroll back up to see the updated value. Anyone know a fix?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var beeslevel: [Int] {
        return [beelevel, wasplevel, bumblebeelevel]
    }
    var beelevel = 0
    var wasplevel = 0
    var bumblebeelevel = 0
    let bees = ["bee", "wasp", "bumblebee"]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(bees.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        cell.beeimage.image = UIImage(named: bees[indexPath.row] + ".png")
        cell.beelabel.text = bees[indexPath.row]
        cell.beelevel.text = "lvl \(beeslevel[indexPath.row])"

        return(cell)
    }

    @IBAction func beelevelup(_ sender: Any) {
        beelevelup()
    }

    func beelevelup() {
        beelevel += 1
        score -= 50
    }
```

Comment: you need to reload table with new array data.

Comment: What command/code would I use? Or how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If I have got the question correctly, you actually want a row of a TableView which contains player's information, to be updated whenever it levels up.

You need to reload the cell by writing the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var players:[String]?
    var tableView: UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        players = ["Ronaldo", "Ronaldinho", "Messi", "Suarez", "Neymar", "Pogba", "Pele", "Rooney", "Ozil"]

        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView?.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 20, width: 200, height: 500)
        tableView?.dataSource = self
        tableView?.delegate  = self
        tableView?.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        view.addSubview(tableView!)

        let button = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.setTitle("Update Data", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: tableView!.frame.origin.y + tableView!.frame.size.height+20, width: tableView!.frame.width, height: 50)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRowUpdate), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (players?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = players?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func onRowUpdate() {
        let index = NSIndexPath.init(item: 2, section: 0)
        players?[index.row] = "Traxido"
        tableView!.reloadRows(at: [index as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is in Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: I understand but it was just for information, but still I will update it

Comment: There is no need for the calls to `begin/endUpdates` when you use a single call to update the table.

Comment: Apple Developer API Reference :      beginUpdates() and  endUpdates() These method pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid.

Comment: I assure you that those calls are not need in this case. Try it. You only need them if you make multiple calls to `insert/delete/move/reloadRows` and you need their index paths to match up.

Comment: Ok but reloadRows  always takes an array of indexPaths and in this scenario he may be updating multiple rows at a time

Comment: But it's just a single call. Doesn't matter how many rows you pass in. All that matters is how many calls to `insert/delete/move/reloadRows` you make, not the number of rows.

Comment: @Saurav This still isn't working, I have to manually pull down/ scroll down to reload the cell...

Comment: It should work provided you are 1. Passing the correct indexPath 2. Your array which have data is updated with latest data

Comment: You can test it by putting a breakpoint inside cellforrowatindexpath method that if is it getting called when you reload the row

Comment: Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place, where in the code should this be implemented?

Comment: @Saurav It's almost like it doesn't recognize that I triggered the upgrade button, until I scroll down